# Tamaño de ListView en Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, listview, xamarin.forms

Estoy trabajando con ListView en Xamarin, el problema que he visto en este dia, es que el ListView no se ajusta a la altura del contenido de datos.

Para muestra aqui esta la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este ListView contiene solo 4 registros, y del cuarto al final de la listview tiene un gran espacio vacio, esperaba que se auto ajustara.

Ya que no se pudo, busque info en internet y encontre este articulo: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19874/listview-inside-stacklayout-a-height-problem

***En donde dice que meta el ListView dentro de un Stacklayout con la Vertical Option en FillandExpand pero aun asi me da este espacio no deseado***.

Tendran alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setea la propiedad HasUnevenRows en el listview en true o false según tu necesidad. Esta propiedad es para que el registro tome su tamaño adecuado si es mas grande que otro registro.

**Edito la respuesta para adaptarla.**

Proba usar la etiqueta Footer y agrega un boton.

```
<ListView x:Name="lst_items">
            <ListView.Footer>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Button Text="Regresar a Menu"></Button>
                </StackLayout>
            </ListView.Footer>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: Ramiro, en este caso si pongo HasUnevenRows = True se hace mas grande el espacio, y si pongo HasUnevenRows = False, se mantiene el mismo tamaño, alguna otra idea?

Comment: Entendí mal la pregunta, el problema no es el último registro sino el listview que queres que se adapte a la pantalla, de esa manera queres que el botón suba o baje? En el fillandexpand carga y expande tu control a toda la pantalla

Comment: Correcto @RamiroBarone, quisiera que el boton se mueva acorde al tamaño de ListView.

Comment: @RamiroBarone Gracias Ramiro resolvio mi problema!!!

Answer (score 0):

Coloca el listview en un stacklayout o grid pero no le des ninguna propiedad vertical, fuera del stacklayout o grid pon el boton y ya cargara bajo el listview